# Calling activity intent in Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to call a activity class from a fragment. I have implemented OnClickListener and it's method too.

```
    if(v.getId() == sortbutton.getId())
    {
        //callSorting();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EMB_SortList.class);
        //startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_LEVEL);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Here is my java file:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener 
{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    if (rootView != null) 
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();

        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try 
    {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
    } 
    catch (InflateException e) 
    {

    }

    sortbutton = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sortText);
    sortbutton.setOnClickListener(this);        

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

but I am getting a strange error.

```
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.ylg.Link/com.ylg.Link.SortList} did not call through to super.onCreate()
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
03-16 19:40:20.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1346):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not sure what is wrong here? Can somebody help me fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: you forgot to call `super.onCreate()`

Comment: @Blackbelt - Can you please explain or give me an example?

Comment: that you overrode onCreate and you didn't call the super

Comment: I am not calling OnCreate at all. As it is Fragement I am using the public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: Do you extend Fragment or Activty for the class in the called Activity/Fragment.

Comment: Fragment. check the update in my question

Comment: Remove the overriden method OnCreate from your fragment since you do nothing on that place. and you are posting the class file which calls the Activity not the class which you are starting from the intent. please post the code of EMB_SortList.Java not the ListviewFragment.java

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m : Cool. Mate.. You saved my issue. It is was very silly stuff. I didn't call Super.OnCreate() in sortList. Thanks!

Comment: I am so glad that i was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

It obvious that this class isn't using onCreate the right way

```
EMB_SortList.class
```

You need to quadruple check it

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

In fact you need to replace it with one of our answers and make sure you're extending Activity.

---------------------> Dev i think you put this code in your fragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

If you did you need to remove it.

That code doesn't go in your fragment it goes in the activity you want to create.

Comment: Still the same.. Doesn't change. Gives me the same error

Comment: I see you have another problem check answer

Comment: still the same problem. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Add `this.getActivity()` in the place of `getActivity()`

```
if(v.getId() == sortbutton.getId())
    {
        //callSorting();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), EMB_SortList.class);
        //startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_LEVEL);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Probably you didn't add the super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
in the very first line of the onCreate method your SortList activity.

Answer (score 1):

> android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.ylg.Link/com.ylg.Link.SortList} did not call through to super.onCreate()

It seems u have forgotted to call `super.onCreate()` method in `onCreate()` method of the activity

Answer (score 1):

In the EMB_Sortlist.java Class add

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //You should override the below method
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //Do your work here
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code in the onCreate of the that class?

Comment: I don't anything in that case. It is exactly the same like above. I am just using public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  if (rootView != null) 
  {
   ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();

   if (parent != null)
    parent.removeView(rootView);
  }
  try 
  {
   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout_list, container, false);
  } 
  catch (InflateException e) 
  {

  }

Comment: I doubt that you  are giving an fragment class to an activity it would be better if you could provide the whole code of that class file. the fragment from which you start the activity and the activity you are starting. PS- dont paste the code here, Update your OP instead.